# not able to search text in a dataTable using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a textbox. onkeyup() event, i need to search in each column of the dataTable and show all the rows that matches with the keyword typed.

my jquery function is as follows:

```
var myTable= $('#tbl').dataTable();

$("#txtsearch").keyup( function () {

 myTable.fnFilter( this.value, $("#txtsearch").index(this) );     

      });
```

But this is not working for me.
Please anybody help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

var myTable= $(#tbl").dataTable();

$("#txtsearch").keyup(function(){

```
myTable.fnFilter($(this).val());
```

});